# get value of selected index of combo box in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get the value of the selected index in my javascript

here i am defining my list box

```
<select name="combo" id="combo"  OnBlur="retrieveData(this.form)" ></select>
```

here i am trying to get the value (inside the form)

```
    alert(form.combo.value); // NOT working
    alert(form.combo.selectedIndex)  // working
    alert(form.combo.selectedIndex.value)  // NOT working
```

but its showing "undefined"

Comment: Show your `retrieveData` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
form.combo.options[form.combo.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: The `value` property of the `<select>` element should reflect the selected option's value. Given a singular selection scenario, `select.value` should suffice. The OP may be leaving out a few details, because it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
in your html:

```
<select name="combo" id="combo" OnBlur="getComboVal(this)" ></select>
```

in javascript:

```
function getComboVal(sel)
{
    alert (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
}
```